# Remove characters after any tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working in rails. I have one doubt.

```
  1. a = "ABCD123"
     I want to print ABCD123

  2. b = "ABCDE<123>"
     I want to print ABCDE
```

For that I am using this

```
a.scan(/\b[A-Za-z]+\b/).join and 

b.scan(/\b[A-Za-z]+\b/).join.
```

First one is giving nil but I want to print it as ABCD123 and second one is showing correct what I want.

Could anyone please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to remove HTML markup from your string? Where are those `<123>` things coming from?

Comment: What is the expected result when the input is `ABC123DEF`? `ABC` or `ABCDEF`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def conversion(str)
  index_number = str.index(/[\W_]+/)
  if index_number.present?
    main_str = str.gsub(str[index_number..],'')
  else
    main_str = str
  end
  return main_str
end
```

or you can use

`b = "ABCD-123"
 b.match(/(^[A-Za-z0-9]+)/)[1]
 #=> "ABCD"`

Comment: For the 1st one I am seeing only ABCD, I wants to print ABCD123.
for the 2nd one it's fine.

Comment: @KumarNikhil It is already "ABCD123".Please check latest edit of mine

Comment: for 2nd if I will add ABCD-1234, then I want to print ABCD.

Comment: @KumarNikhil when first character of not number and not alphabetic get it will remove remaining string include that character though please check latest code or you can direct use b.match(/(^[A-Za-z0-9]+)/) it is upto you

Answer (score 1):

code below can remove all tags in the string

```rb
a = "ABCD123"
b = "ABCDE<123>"

a.gsub /<.*?>/, ''     # => "ABCD123"
b.gsub /<.*?>/, ''     # => "ABCDE"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following,

```
b = "ABCDE<123>"
b[/[^<>]+/]
# => "ABCDE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since comments are a bit limited:

Here is a small snippet to test different inputs.

```rb
strings = %w[ABCD123 ABCD<123> ABCD <123>ABCDE]

strings.each do |string|
  match = string.match(/(^[A-Za-z0-9]+)/)
  if match
    puts "'#{string}' => #{match[1]}"
  else
    puts "'#{string}' does not match pattern"
  end
end
```

Is this the desired behaviour?

```
'ABCD123' => ABCD123
'ABCD<123>' => ABCD
'ABCD' => ABCD
'<123>ABCDE' does not match pattern
```